# Does Unity render invisible material?

Tags: unity-game-engine, gpu, render

If all parameters are set to make it completely transparent, making it impossible to see, will Unity still render it? If yes, are there built-in Unity functions to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

**short answer:** yes, if it's there and active it will be rendered

**long answer:** if there is a material that can be transparent unity don't know if it's 0% transparent or 80% or 100% it will be rendered, if it's completely transparent unity HAVE to render it to know that, it means when unity understand it that it's already too late :)
if you want anything not to render, deactivate it.